# displaying loading spinner while jquery calls Controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a jquery function in my View(Index.cshtml)...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // call ASP.NET MVC Controller and return value of Checkboxes as string array
    function SerializeMappings()
    {
        var matches = [];

        $('[class^="mappings_"]:checked').each(function () {
            matches.push(this.value);
        });

        $.post("/Home/Validate", { listofmappings: matches }, function (data) {
            document.write(data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

This function calls this function:

```
    // POST: Home/Validate
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Validate(string[] listOfMappings)
    {
       //Some code which takes Long time (~10-15sec)
       //....
       //fill List<List<string>> with data and return it to Validate.cshtml

       return View(anyStringList);
    }
```

Now my real question: How can I display a loading circle while the 'Validate' function is running...? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` function to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some different approaches.

---

The basic one is to show the spinner just before the post and hide it when the call is ended, as follows:

```
// Here you show the spinner
...
$.post("/Home/Validate", { listofmappings: matches }, function (data) {
    document.write(data);
})
.always(function() {
    // Here you hide the spinner
    ...
});;
```

---

Another approach, if you are using a layout and you want to standardize and centralize the management of the spinner is to use [jQuery Global Ajax Event Handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/).

First you let jQuery know that when you launch an Ajax request you want to show the spinner that will be located in your layout:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function () {
        // Here you show your spinner
        ...
    }
});
```

When every request is completed, you just hide the spinner:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    // Here you hide the spinner
    ...
});
```

The same thing can be accomplished as Azim suggested in his comment, using `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop`.

Comment: Thanks bro, that helped me a lot!

Comment: @H.Senkaya no problem, I'm glad it helped you ;)